# How to initialize views (ToggleButtons) array?

Tags: android, view, array-initialization

I have 11 ToggleButtons in an activity, and at the moment, in the onCreate I declare an array of 11 ToggleButtons, that I define in onCreate(), like that:

```
private static ToggleButton toggleButton[] = new ToggleButton[11];
```

...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toggleButton[0] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton00);
    toggleButton[1] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);
    toggleButton[2] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton02);
    toggleButton[3] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton03);
    toggleButton[4] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton04);
    toggleButton[5] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton05);
    toggleButton[6] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton06);
    toggleButton[7] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton07);
    toggleButton[8] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton08);
    toggleButton[9] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton09);
    toggleButton[10] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton10);
```

I'm sure there should be a better way (like a loop), any idea? How would you do that?

Comment: you can loop on layout it self and assign each togglebutton to array in this loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
ToggleButton toggleButton[] = new ToggleButton[11];
    int arrayindex = 0;
    int viewcount = 0;
    while (arrayindex < 11) {

        View v = asyncLayout.getChildAt(viewcount);
        if (v instanceof ToggleButton) {

            toggleButton[arrayindex] = (ToggleButton) v;
            arrayindex ++;
        }
        viewcount ++ ;

    }
```

feed me back in any issue

Comment: There could be any number of children that aren't ToggleButtons. So the toggleButton[] can easily go out of bounds and cause an exception.

Comment: it is not the final code , it's just to  clarify the idea , i don't know its layout , just 11 togglebutton , by the way i will modify the code

Comment: @NickT i modified  the code and test it with children that aren't ToggleButtons

Comment: Can't say it's the most elegant piece of code that I've seen, but as you've tested it and it doesn't crash, I'll undo the downvote.